# TeamCity build specific container based on last commit

Tags: git, docker, bitbucket, teamcity

I created job in TeamCity which allows me to checkout from multiple VCSs and create docker images with maven command, then deploy it to Kubernetes.
In one of VCS I have docker-compose.yml file, where defined a lot of services, such like:

```
>   turbinenode:
    image: turbinenode
    build: ./turbinenode
    hostname: 127.0.0.1
    container_name: turbinenode
...
  hystrixnode:
    image: hystrixnode
    build: ./hystrixnode
    container_name: hystrixnode
...

  zipkinnode:
    image: zipkinnode
    build: ./zipkinnode
    container_name: zipkinnode
...
```

Each of this services has folders with source files, Dockerfiles in them.
Now I need to have config in my job to build only that service, in where were changes by git commit, thus detect where was git commit and build only that docker image.

Comment: why not to build dockers in a separate jobs that depends on one VCS. and create a separate deployment job that depends on artifacts of docker build job and triggered by this dependency.

Comment: there are more than 100 services in docker compose file, do I should to have separate jobs for each of them?